# Simple loop doen't show the result to output in R

Tags: r

I have written a simple loop in R in Rstudio

```
it=10:110
for(i in it)
{
  sprintf("partial r2 for iteration %f is %f....",i,0.0)
}
```

But above code doesn't prompt results in console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap `sprintf()` inside `cat()` or `message()`, like this:

```
it=10:110
for(i in it)
{
  cat(sprintf("partial r2 for iteration %f is %f....",i,0.0))
}
```